# Nominal input current of a switching mode power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, high-voltage, mains

I was simply trying to design a constant voltage switching mode power supply for a small side project I have. 85 - 275 VAC input and 50 V constant output.

As far as current regulation goes, a lot of the designs available online have a combination of fuses and varistors that can cut off the circuit when there is a voltage/current surge, but I am curious as to how I would calculate the maximum nominal current that flows through the circuit during normal operation (i.e. when there is no surge).

Is this an important thing in the design? I think it is required to find the average input power so I can calculate the nominal output current by equating input power and output power (while also taking into account the efficiency). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : Furthering this line of questioning - how can we fix a maximum output current in a constant voltage power source ?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - nominal input current is output power divided by input voltage and again divided by efficiency.

Highest input current occurs at lowest input voltage. Be aware also of surges when power is initially applied and charges the internal capacitors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In that case, how can we fix a maximum output current in the design ?

Comment: IOUT_MAX = VIN/VOUT * I_IN * efficiency
 
if you don't know efficiency, 80 % may be a reasonable guess. While VIN may be nominally, if can be as low as 90 V in some '110V' environments